# How to send arraylist of objects using addFormDataPart by retrofit?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

I have request body like this and it contains array of objects

```
{
    "api_token" : "1572370159",
    "latt":29.970245729247,
    "lang": 31.14269679235,
    "patient_id":1,
    "insurance" : 0,
    "delivery" : 0,
    "notes": "notes",
    "photo": "",
    "orderDetails": [

        {"medicine_id": 1, "medicine_type_id": 1, "amount": 2},
        {"medicine_id": 1, "medicine_type_id": 1, "amount": 2},
        {"medicine_id": 1, "medicine_type_id": 1, "amount": 2},
        {"medicine_id": 1, "medicine_type_id": 1, "amount": 2},
        {"medicine_id": 1, "medicine_type_id": 1, "amount": 2},
        {"medicine_id": 1, "medicine_type_id": 1, "amount": 2},
        {"medicine_id": 1, "medicine_type_id": 1, "amount": 2},
        {"medicine_id": 1, "medicine_type_id": 1, "amount": 2},
        {"medicine_id": 1, "medicine_type_id": 1, "amount": 2},
        {"medicine_id": 2, "medicine_type_id": 2, "amount": 1}
    ]
}
```

everything goes fine if I didn't send orderDetails
so how I send it
here is my code :

my endpoint

```
@POST("pharmacy/order/create")
    fun createPharmacyOrder(@Body requestBody: RequestBody)
            : Call<PharmacyOrderResponse>
```

Here is the code which tries to send this list using addFormDataPart

```
fun createPharmacyOrder(request :MedicineOrderRequest, callback: BaseResponseListener<PharmacyOrderResponse>) {
        val builder = MultipartBody.Builder()
        builder.setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
        builder.addFormDataPart("api_token" , request.api_token)
        builder.addFormDataPart("latt" , request.latt.toString())
        builder.addFormDataPart("lang" , request.lang.toString())
        builder.addFormDataPart("patient_id" , request.patient_id.toString())
        builder.addFormDataPart("insurance" , request.insurance.toString())
        builder.addFormDataPart("delivery" , request.delivery.toString())
        builder.addFormDataPart("notes" , request.notes)
        //request.orderDetails: ArrayList<OrderDetail>
        if (request.orderDetails.size > 0)
                builder.addFormDataPart("orderDetails"
                    , Gson().toJson(request.orderDetails)
                )

        if (!request.photo.equals("")) {
            with(File(request.photo)){
                builder.addPart(MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("photo",name
                , RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"),this)))
            }
        }

        val service = ApiConfigure.mainRetrofit.create(ApiEndPoint::class.java)
        val call: Call<PharmacyOrderResponse> = service.createPharmacyOrder(builder.build())
        call.start(callback)
    }
```

Comment: first of all, do you want to send MedicineOrderRequest like a dto body (json), or like form data? Form data usually is used for straems (files for examlpe), simple DTOs usually are sended as request body

Comment: I want to send it like form data because I want to send an image as well

Comment: Try something like that: `builder.addFormDataPart("data" , Gson().toJson(request))`. Data should contain json of `MedicineOrderRequest `

Comment: Thanks but I already used your solution and I used gson as shown in my code and it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use [] in the key.
Like this:

builder.addFormDataPart("orderDetails[]", Gson().toJson(request.orderDetails))